# Why my list view which is filtering items based on an Indexed column, and which will return 2950 items, will show threshold error for end users

Tags: 2013, list, administration, list-view-threshold, large-lists

I am facing this strange and UN-logical behavior inside our custom list view. now we have a sharepoint enterprise farm 2013. and the list threshold for the web application is set to the defualt which is 5,000. but i am facing this scenario:-

1. I have added the "Created By" column inside the Index columns for the custom list.
2. I defined a list view which will show items that were created by the "System Account" and sort items using the Id, as follow:-
   [image]
3. then using the site admin, i accessed the list view and i can view all items which equal to 2949, as follow :-

[image]

**4. so now  since i am filtering using an Indexed column (Created By) + i am sorting using the ID + the total number of items = 2949, so i were assuming that end users will be able to access the list view, but when they do so they got threshold exception, as follow:-**
[image]

So can anyone advice on this please?

note. now we have another Indexed columns named "Alert Period in month" of type number, and i define another view with this filter/sort:-
[image]

and the number of items on the view will be equal to 350, and end users were able to access this list view.. **so is the issue i am facing on my first list view is with the Indexed column (created-by) OR the problem with the number of item which is 2949, although it is below the threshold which is 5,000??**

Comment: Can you guess the total number of records in the list? You may need to wait for the indexing job to finish depending on the number of records.

Comment: @AhmadZia the list contain 6350 items and i run a full crawl twice , but did not fix the issues.. also i did an index reset and run another full crawl without any positive results...

Comment: It appears that its a known issue with "Created By" indexed column https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e666f850-7e6b-4530-a95e-9abae264775e/indexed-column-with-created-by-field-does-not-work?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious unless someone has a solution or work around.

Comment: @AhmadZia looks from the link that this problem is happening inside sharepoint 2010, and it did not get fixed till now on sharepoint 2013 !!!!